# Como puedo mostrar una diagonal invertida "\" en mi código

Tags: java

```java
public class Matric {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Formador: Edy1999
    int np=8;
    int nh=27;
    //Creando el arreglo
    String casaSim [][] = new String [50][50];
    int LimH=0;
        for (int p = 1; p < np; p++) {
            for (int h = 1; h < nh; h++) {
                if (p!=1 & (h<=LimH || h>(nh-LimH-1))) {
                   casaSim[p][h]="/";
                
                }
                else{
                    casaSim[p][h]="!";
                }
            }//Fin del r de las habi
            LimH += 2;
        }//Fin del r de los pisos
        
        //Mostrando a mis inquilinos
            //Formador Edy1999
                for (int p = 1; p < np; p++) {
            for (int h = 1; h < nh; h++) {
                System.out.print(casaSim[p][h]+" ");
            }//Fin del r de las habi
            System.out.println("");
        }//Fin del r de los pisos
        
    }// fin del main
    
}
```

Me sale esto al ejecutar el programa

```
! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! !
 
/ / ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / 

/ / / / ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / 

/ / / / / / ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / / / 

/ / / / / / / / ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / / / / / 

/ / / / / / / / / / ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / / / / / / / 

/ / / / / / / / / / / / ! ! / / / / / / / / / / / /
```

Pero tiene que ser con diagonal invertida al inicio
Algo así

```
! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! 

\ \ ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / 

\ \ \ \ ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / 

\ \ \ \ \ \ ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / / / 

\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / / / / / 

\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / / / / / / / 

\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ! ! / / / / / / / / / / / /
```

Comment: Hola, como tal que es lo que dice tu ejercicio que tienes que hacer

Comment: Crear mediante una matriz el siguiente diseño, el que esta ahí arriba de los signos de admiración y de diagonal invertida

Comment: Socio, tienes que decir mas cosas, como cual es la longitud de la matriz, como se distribuyen los caracteres, tu piensas que alguien se va a poner a contar los signos de exclamacion con que empieza la matriz, tienes q explicarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Para imprimir la diagonal invertida colocas dentro de las comillas

```
casaSim[p][h]="\\";
```

y eso es todo, xq si colocas una sóla diagonal te marca un error.

Espero te sirva de algo

Answer (score 0):

La cosa es que tu lógica siempre imprime barras de tipo "/" si quieres imprimir barras invertidas al principio "\" y al final las barras "/" tienes que cambiar tu lógica del código.

Si no se te imprimen las barras invertidas utiliza:

```
casaSim[p][h]="\\";
```

Eso ayudara a imprimir barras invertidas si no se imprimen.